# phpbb banning multiple users by username/email

Tags: phpbb, spam-prevention

On phpbb, we usually select many user names and put it in the ban list. This is fine. but here's my key question:

Are these banned users banned by their user names only OR emails OR both?

If they're banned by user names only, is it possible to black-list their email addresses as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `Administration Panel > General > User registration settings > Allow e-mail address re-use` and set that to no, users wont be able to register using the email address of another member. So, if you ban someone, there email address can't be used again. Likewise, you can set that to yes if you want people to be able to reuse email addresses.

Also, if you go to `Moderator Control Panel > Banning > Ban e-mails` or `Administration Panel > Users and Groups > Ban e-mails`, you can ban email addresses there. That gives you more options, because you can use wildcard matching to, for example, ban emails that use certain domains (i.e. no emails from `gmail.com`), or ban any email that contains the word spam.

Keep in mind, though, that spammers usually just create a new email address, and that they don't usually reuse them. This will more likely stop real people, who usually are too lazy to create another email adress.

Answer (score -1):

Depends. If you ban them by user names, they're banned only by user name. But since the email address is associated is with an existing account, phpBB won't allow another person to user the same email id.

It's also possible to ban by email ids

Comment: This could be wrong (depending on phpbb settings): there is an option that could be disabled that would stop phpbb from checking to see if emails were already used by members.